# how to create a versioned dll

Tags: c++, windows, dll, versioning

can someone help me write or give an example for a versioned DLL ?
I want to create a function that during the compilation - sets all the details of the DLL but I don't know how to do it , and even how to start or where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three steps involved are:

1. Create a [version resource script](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/Resource_Script_Reference#Version_Information).
2. Compile the version resource script using the [resource compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
3. Link the compiled resource file (suffix `.res`) into the DLL.

Example:

- main.cpp

  ```
  #include <windows.h>
  BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE, DWORD, LPVOID) { return TRUE; }
  ```
- version.rc

  ```
  #define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
  #include "windows.h"
  #undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

  LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_UK
  #pragma code_page(1252)

  VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
   FILEVERSION 1,9,1,7
   PRODUCTVERSION 2,2,2,2
   FILEFLAGSMASK 0x3fL
   FILEFLAGS 0x0L
   FILEOS 0x40004L
   FILETYPE 0x1L
   FILESUBTYPE 0x0L
  BEGIN
      BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
      BEGIN
          BLOCK "080904b0"
          BEGIN
              VALUE "CompanyName", "My Company.\0"
              VALUE "FileDescription", "My File\0"
              VALUE "FileVersion", "1.9.1.7\0"
              VALUE "InternalName", "my-real-file\0"
              VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright © 2012 My Company Ltd.\0"
              VALUE "OriginalFilename", "my.dll\0"
              VALUE "PrivateBuild", "820\0"
              VALUE "ProductName", "My Company: my dll\0"
              VALUE "ProductVersion", "2.2.2.2\0"
          END
      END
      BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
      BEGIN
          VALUE "Translation", 0x809, 1200
      END
  END
  ```

From the command-line:

```
> rc version.rc

> cl /nologo /LD main.cpp version.RES
main.cpp
```

This creates a `main.dll` with a *Version* tab.

*Caveat: It has been quite a while since I looked at this and have forgotten what all the content in version.rc script means.*

Comment: Im sorry for the question , but is this C++? it has BEGIN , END, BLOCK and VALUE.. what is this language ? and should I add a .rc file to my project that I open in VS2010? Im soo confused

Comment: The resource script is not C++. If you follow the link to the resource compiler you can find out more about script content. As for using the VS2010 IDE I am afraid I cannot assist as I don't use IDEs. I suspect the IDE generates the script for you.

Comment: how can I link it later? I'm using VS and the pre-build properties and I want to add it there , should I give the full path of the dll project? and then use : fo/ resource.rc ? then I should get the RES file , and then what? how can I link it? should I use the post-build properties?